# SEF turned on, stops the Country States dropdown in checkout Virtuemart 3.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, sef, dropdown

I have an issue with SEF, when turned on it stops the States dropdown in checkout Virtuemart 3 and Viostore Template.
Trying to customise some SEO which recommends SEF as a one of the requirements.

I have Sitemap and RSSeo installed and thought it was a conflict but it makes no difference if the plugins are disabled.

I first thought it was Virtuemart and went through the hoops with there help support with the following response…

Re: Country States not displaying on dropdown
Message: Hi, As mentioned before, this is not a Template related issue. In this case please try to ask about this at Virtuemart forum. Regards, Paul.

I did this, and no response.

All VM 3.2. and Joomla 3.6.5.up to date.
Hope someone has come across this and has an answer.
Thanks
G